# Odoo select all records where user is follower

Tags: search, conditional-statements, odoo, selection

Can somebody give me example (or hint) how to select all records where user is follower?
I cant find any information about handling followers. What the condition should be?

```
find_record = self.env['my_class'].search([( **user is floower** )])
```

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get better answers. Tell us more about your problem, your platform and how your solution is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followers are related to partners, you can select records where current user related partner is in followers:

```
self.env['sale.order'].search([('message_follower_ids.partner_id', '=', self.env.user.partner_id.id)])
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try the following

first element of the tuple : the partner id related to the user

2nd element of the tuple : the logical operator 'in'

3rd element of the tuple : the id of partners following the record

```
self.env['helpdesk.ticket'].search([(self.env.user.partner_id.id, 'in', 'message_follower_ids.partner_id')])
```

Comment: A [domain](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#domains) is a list of criteria, each criterion being a triple (either a `list` or a `tuple`) of (`field_name, operator, value`)